# K8S port forward to Service in secure cluster

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding

From past 1 year we are working on K8S environment where each user has the access to all namespaces. But as we are introducing new applications in cluster it is important to grant only required access to a user .

We have few services which runs in a namespace e.g. ABC. As there were no restrictions users were able to port forward the service and access it. With new restrictions now they are not able to access those services.

Is there a way to grant access to users for port-forward which will not compromise the security ?

Comment: If I understand correct what you need is to add rbac, which  is a method of regulating access to computer or network resources based on the roles of individual users within your organization. Could you try to create a role and rolebinding as shown in the example [here](https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-rbac-port-forward-4c7eb3951e28) and check if it works?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called **RBAC**.

> Role-based access control (RBAC) is a method of regulating access to computer or network resources based on the roles of individual users within your organization.
>
> RBAC authorization uses the rbac.authorization.k8s.io API group to drive authorization decisions, allowing you to dynamically configure policies through the Kubernetes API.

RBAC auth rules are configured with K8s resources which can be placed in two groups:

- `Role` and `ClusterRole` contains rules that represent a set of permissions, it specify which actions can be performed on which resources, if you want to define a role within a namespace, use a `Role`, if you want to define a role cluster-wide, use a `ClusterRole`. More about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole).
- `RoleBindings` and `ClusterRoleBindings` binds above `role` and `ClusterRole` to specific list of subjects(users,groups,service accounts). A RoleBinding grants permissions within a specific namespace whereas a ClusterRoleBinding grants that access cluster-wide. More about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding).

---

There is an example `Role` and `RoleBinding` for `kubectl port-forward` from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-rbac-port-forward-4c7eb3951e28).

> To take this example even further, let’s say that you want to give a person access to only port-forward. You will have to create an RBAC role that lets this person only do this:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  name: allow-port-forward
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "pods/portforward"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "create"]
```

> This sets up a role in the namespace my-namespace and allows this role to get, list, and create on pods and pods/portforward. These are all of the permissions needed to allow someone to port-forward. This person will be able to list the pods in this namespace.
> Then you bind this role to a user:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: allow-port-forward
  namespace: my-namespace
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: bob
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: allow-port-forward
  apiGroup: ""
```

> This will give the **user bob** the rights to perform the above actions in the **namespace my-namespace**

---

So the answer here would be to add add rbac auth rules for every user which should be able to use `kubectl port-forward`.

---